# Dilated polygon sides position

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

Must the sides of a dilated polygon always be parallel to the original ones, given that both polygons (original and dilated) have the same centroid coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the scale factor is a non-negative value, because the dilation is a uniform scaling and the polygons have congruent corresponding angles, so their shapes are similar:

[polygons dilation visualization](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry-home/transformations/dilations-scaling/v/dilating-from-an-arbitrary-point-example)

[similarity and dilations](http://www.brainfuse.com/curriculumupload/1336403025157.html)